# PHP reading file into variable

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to store a txt file in a php variable, I have the functionality working already, but there's one issue I cant really wrap my head around.

I want to read the file using variables as the name of such file, and when I do so, the script doesn't read the file, but when I explicitly code the name, it works ok.

I have the following code:

```
$mga_file[] = "./MGA/mga_" . preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z]", "", trim(strtolower($ar_mga[0]))) . "_" . preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z]", "", trim(strtolower($db_producto))) . ".txt";
$mga_file[] = "./MGA/mga_" . preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z]", "", trim(strtolower($ar_mga[0]))) . "_led.txt";
$mga_file[] = "./MGA/mga_high_led.txt";
$mga_file[] = "./MGA/mga_high_".strtolower($db_producto).".txt";
```

I edited the code thinking my variable `$ar_mga[0]` might have other characters, but still it doesn't work. Using this array, and the following code, I have different results:

```
foreach($mga_file as $file){
  $homepage = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
  echo "[" . $file . "] : ";
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($homepage); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Gives me the following results:

```
Array [$mga_file]
(
    [0] => ./MGA/mga_high_led.txt //Not Working
    [1] => ./MGA/mga_high_led.txt //Not Working
    [2] => ./MGA/mga_high_led.txt //Working
    [3] => ./MGA/mga_high_led.txt //Working
)
```

As you can see, the file name is exactly the same on all 4 values, what could happening that I only read the file on the last 2 values?

EDIT:
Seems I overlooked one huge detail, the `$ar_mga[0]` variable contained the value I was trying to use, but it was enclosed on a span tag (which I never saw until I examined the page html), and never worked because of this. Striping the tag from the variable made the script work correctly.

My bad!

Comment: That is really strange. The filename is just a string, whether you build it dynamically or not doesn't matter. One thing that is a potential issue is the use of `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH`. Just make an absolute path, there is no reason not to. Don't use `print_r()` to print strings. `print_r()` is for arrays. A good debug value printer is `var_dump()`, if you have recursion use `print_r` as a fallback.

Comment: I already tried using absolute paths, and the same issue happens.

Comment: Is the file available when you try to read it? Does it exist? What is the output of `file_get_contents`? Do you get an error?

Comment: I get no error, and as I said, the last 2 values do return the contents of the file, only the first 2 fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I overlooked one huge detail, the `$ar_mga[0]` variable contained the value I was trying to use, but it was enclosed on a span tag (which I never saw until I examined the page html), and never worked because of this. Striping the tag from the variable made the script work correctly.

My bad!